# Configuring the latest version of AutoMapper at the Global.asax level in an ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to figure out how to configure the new AutoMapper at the Global.asax level.

**I used to do the following with old AutoMapper:**

Create a class in App_Start folder called MappingProfile.cs and in the constructor I would add my mappings like this:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
     Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
     Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
}
```

Then in Global.asax call:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
```

Can someone please tell me how to achieve the above with the new version of AutoMapper? I have been reading the docs but can't seem to get it.

**I believe I do something like this in my MappingProfile.cs file:**

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
       cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
       cfg.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
    });
```

but what do I do with the config variable?

Comment: Did you check the [readme](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/) blog post?

Comment: Yes, I read both that and the new AutoMapper documentation and there is no straight forward example on what I am supposed to be calling in Global.Asax and how I create a MapperProfile class.

Comment: The docs are much too brief. I'm just trying to learn how to use AutoMapper and 3 days in, still don't know how to use it. Having round after round of deprecations isn't helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do it.

```
public abstract class AutoMapperBase
{
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    protected AutoMapperBase()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
        {
            x.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
            x.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
        });

        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

Then inherit AutoMapperBase from any class which needs to use it, and call it like this:

```
var foo = _mapper.Map<ProductDto>(someProduct);
```

You no longer need it declared or configured in Global.asax

Comment: Ok so I created your AutoMapperBase class, now in an ApiController how do I use it if the class is already inheriting from ApiController. Multiple inheritiance is only allowed through Interfaces

Comment: You could move this code out of a class and into the constructor of your Controller class, or inherit ApiController from AutoMapperBase.  In the latter case I would rename AutoMapperBase to AutoMapperApiControllerBase or something more obvious as to it's use.

Comment: Is there even a point in doing any of this? It seems as if they want you to initialize it for each specific scenario in each file. This is really a pain, and why is it for the better? What are they recommending in the documentation?

Comment: I prefer it. Personally I find it's more obvious than when it's hidden away in a global.asax file.  But this is the answer to your specific question.

Comment: I got ya, I agree you answered it well. However, your saying there is nothing wrong with using Mapper.Initialize on the fly then calling Mapper.Map afterwards in all cases?

Comment: The old way of doing it required you to Initialize once, and call the static Mapper instance that gets created when you need to use it.  You certainly wouldn't initialize in more than one place using the original method. That isn't correct.

Comment: @IntoNET - I am trying to convert an ASP.Net site to the newer AutoMapper, which prevents me from using the Static.  The AutoMapper Getting Started (https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) says " Configuration should only happen once per AppDomain. That means the best place to put the configuration code is in application startup, such as the Global.asax file for ASP.NET applications."  However, yours seems that it would call it every time a page is called.  Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is the following:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
    cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
});
```

This will configure the static mapper instance that was exposed in the old AutoMapper so that you can do:

```
Mapper.Map<SomeType>(fromObject);
```

If you don't want to use the static instance then you need to look at the IntoNET answer.

The "CreateMissingTypeMaps" line ensures that missing mappings are created "on the fly". It's the equivalent of the old:

```
Mapper.DynamicMap<SomeType>(fromObject)
```

If you want to define each mapping by hand you can remove this line.

There was a version of AutoMapper where author tried to get rid of the exposed static for some reason but he brought it back after public outcry from what I understand. So now you can do it any way you find suitable. You can read about it here:

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/02/24/automapper-4-2-1-released-static-is-back-limited-edition/

Comment: Alright, well I am using version 5.02 which is the latest and greatest. So rather than reconfiguring my mappings in every single file for every single specific use case. How can I do all of the configuration on app startup and then simply call Mapper.Map throughout my code when necessary?

Comment: @BlakeRivell It's right there in my answer. Define your profiles and then use the Initialize method to register them. Put that code in global.asax and you should be able to use Mapper.Map anywhere in your code. Basically calling the Initialize method configures the mappings on the statically exposed IMapper instance.

Comment: I see what your saying so I can simply create a class with a static method called GenerateMappings which I would call in my global.asax file. In GenerateMappings I would call Mapper.Initialize and then finally throughout all of my files I can call Mapper.Map. Does this make sense?

Comment: @BlakeRivell Correct. As a matter of fact that's exactly what we do in our code here... :)

Comment: Got it, so it is either that or simply call Initialize directly in global.asax correct?

Comment: I apologize I can't mark yours as the correct answer because it doesn't answer my original question, but you led me in the path I want to go.